# I am getting Build Failed error in an Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Acer Bilgisayar\Desktop\Android Project\app\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'GradleProjectPlugin'.
      > Could not initialize class com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin
```

build.gradle:

[image: build.gradle]

error:

[image: error]

Comment: What is the Gradle version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Replace jcenter() with mavenCentral() in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```